# Meaning of specific math symbol: "$!!$"

Tags: notation

Can someone please explain me, what does "$!!$" mean? Is it math symbol at all?

I know that it is not factorial, because that's just one "$!$", but I was unable to find any definition for it.

Thanks

Comment: What context was this used in? Can you give an example? Without context, my guess is that it's an iterated factorial. That is $3!!=(3!)!.$

Comment: Sometimes $n!!$ means $n\cdot(n-2)(n-4)\cdots$. (See  Ittps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) It is very unlikely to mean $(n!)!$.

Comment: @Allawonder Incorrect.  It much more commonly refers to the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).  $n!! = n\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-4)\cdot (n-6)\cdots$.  For example $6!! = 6\cdot 4\cdot 2$ while $9!! = 9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 1$.  It comes about as an answer to several counting problems or steps in counting problems, such as the number of ways in which $n$ people may be paired off into groups of two people each.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks a lot

Comment: @MJD thank you so much

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, though I think that's a bad choice of notation, especially as $(2n)(2n-2)\cdots4×2$ may be more simply written as $2^nn!.$

Comment: And $(2n-1)!!$ as $\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, yes those are easily verified identities.  I argue that the identity for $(2n-1)!$ does not simplify matters at all and makes it harder to read while $(2n)!!$ as $2^nn!$ doesn't affect the readability all that much.  "Multiply every other positive integer lower than it" is a straightforward enough concept that it can be visualized at sight rather quickly.  Doing this division of factorials and powers of two, not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n!!$ is known as a "double factorial," or "semifactorial," and it typically represents the product of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ with the same parity (odd or even) as $n$. For example,

$8!! = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8$

$7!! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$

Comment: Oh, okay thanks